# Show $\sum_{c\mid d}\psi(c) = d$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Show  $\sum_{c\mid d}\psi(c) = d$ where $d \mid p-1$ and $\psi(c)$ is the number of elements in $(\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z})^{\star}$ that are of order $c$. $p$ is prime.

I am currently reading through Ireland and Rosen's Number Theory text. I have come across this statement, and I haven't been able to wrap my head around it. I would think that because $c \mid d$ and $d \mid p-1$, $\psi(c) = c$, and so the sum $\sum_{c \mid d}\psi(c) > d$.

Comment: if $c$ is even then both a value and it's additive inverse have the same order, if not one has twice the order.

Comment: $\sum_{c | d}\psi(c)$ is the number of elements whose order divide $d$, there are $d$ of them because $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}^\times$ is cyclic with $p-1$ elements. $\psi(c) = \phi(c)$ not $c$.